# Problem using HttpServletRequest authenticate() within JSF lifecycle

Tags: security, jsf-2, java-ee-6, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to use HttpServletRequest authenticate within a JSF managed bean to implement fine-grained authentication, depending on the particular object requested.

When I call authenticate within a preRenderView event listener, if authenticate causes a redirect to the login page, an exception is thrown.  I can't call responseComplete after the call to authenticate, because FacesContext.getCurrentInstance returns null.  Is it possible to call authenticate() at all in JSF, or do I have to use a ServletFilter? HttpServletRequest login and logout work within JSF, so I think it's reasonable to assume authenticate should work. Is this a bug in Mojarra JSF?

Here is my code:

The page where event listener is registered:

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
<ui:param name="pageTitle" value="Text Clustering Home Page"/>
<ui:define name="metadata">
<f:metadata>

   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{permissionBean.preRender}"/>
</f:metadata>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="body">

      Text Clustering Home Page
      <h:form>
          <h:panelGrid columns="1">
              <ice:outputText rendered="#{loginService.loggedIn}" value="Logged in User: #{loginService.currentUser.username}"/>
              <h:link rendered="#{!loginService.loggedIn}" value="Register" outcome="Register"/>

              <h:commandLink value="Logout" rendered="#{loginService.loggedIn}" action="#{loginService.logout}"/>
              <h:link value="Login" rendered="#{!loginService.loggedIn}" outcome="Login"/>
          </h:panelGrid> 
      </h:form>
```

The bean that contains the listener:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class PermissionBean implements java.io.Serializable {

public void preRender(CompenentSystemEvent event) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
  HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
  try {

      if (!request.authenticate(response)) {
          System.out.println("After authenticate, context = " +FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
          if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()!=null) {                   
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
          }
       }          

  } catch (Exception e) {  // may throw ServletException or IOException
      System.out.println("EXCEPTION calling authenticate");                
      e.printStackTrace();
  }                
}

}
```

The call to authenticate() doesn't throw an exception, but if it returns false, then FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() also returns null, and after the method exits 
I get this error:

```
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context|_ThreadID=23;_Thread
Name=Thread-3;|Exception when handling error trying to reset the
response.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:126    )
```

Thanks,
Ellen

Comment: So it is not null before you call authenticate? Actually, that surprises me. I've however never used it that way before. I think you really need to use a Filter for this.

Comment: I tested it and just before authenticate, it's not null.  I can use a Filter, but it would be much cleaner to put it in a bean, since I need to look at the view parameters to determine if the user needs to be logged in to view the page.  (The page displays an item based on itemId parameter - some items are public and don't require a log in at all, and some are items are restricted.)

Answer (score 1):

From [`HttpServletRequest#authenticate()` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#authenticate%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29):

> ```
> boolean authenticate(HttpServletResponse response)
>                      throws java.io.IOException,
>                             ServletException
> ```
>
> Use the container login mechanism configured for the `ServletContext` to authenticate the user making this request.
>
> **This method may modify and commit the argument `HttpServletResponse`.**

*(emphasis mine)*

The container's implementation will redirect the response to the configured login page when the user has not been authenticated. This has likely also caused the `HttpServletRequest` to be destroyed and thus the current `FacesContext` instance to be completely disappeared.

Your best bet is to let JSF perform the checking the presence of the logged-in user and doing the redirect instead of the container. True, this requires duplicating the login page location in the JSF side, but I don't see other ways which are workable in JSF without moving the task to a `Filter`.

```
public void preRender(CompenentSystemEvent event) {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    if (ec.getUserPrincipal() == null) {
        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
    }
}
```

The [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) will already implicitly call [`FacesContext#responseComplete()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29), so you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, that is a good solution if authentication is always performed in the login page. Unfortunately the other requirement for my app (which I should have mentioned) is that it be configurable to work with other types of authentication as well. For example, we are would like to OpenSSO (now OpenAM) to implement a Single Sign on Solution.  So in order to keep the authentication details out of the code, I need to call authenticate (which lets the container manage the details) instead of doing the redirect in the code.

Comment: It looks like the best bet is to create a Filter that looks up the item, and use CDI to inject the item in the managed bean, that way I won't have to look up the same item twice.